# address of overloaded function does not match required type

Tags: c++, overloading, overload-resolution

So I have am using a constructor that looks like this:

```
deduplicator(std::function<void(const std::vector<uint8_t>&, std::vector<uint8_t>&)> chunk_fingerprinter);
```

and I use this function as the chunk fingerprinter:

```
void sha1_hash(const std::vector<uint8_t>& data, std::vector<uint8_t>& hash);
```

And I initialise the object like this:

```
deduplication::deduplicator dedup = deduplication::deduplicator(harpocrates::hashing::sha1_hash);
```

Which results in this error:

```sh
../src/split-deduplication/split-deduplication.cpp:35:32: error: address of overloaded function 'sha1_hash' does not match required type 'void'
    void* hash_func = (void*) &harpocrates::hashing::sha1_hash;
                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../resolve_symlinks/harpocrates/src/harpocrates/hashing.hpp:34:10: note: candidate function
    void sha1_hash(const std::vector<uint8_t>& data, std::vector<uint8_t>& hash);
         ^
../resolve_symlinks/harpocrates/src/harpocrates/hashing.hpp:40:10: note: candidate function
    void sha1_hash(const uint8_t* data, const size_t size, uint8_t* hash);
```

But if I dabble a bit in the dark arts and do this:

```cpp
    void (*sha1_hash)(const std::vector<uint8_t>&, std::vector<uint8_t>&) = harpocrates::hashing::sha1_hash;
    deduplication::deduplicator dedup = deduplication::deduplicator(sha1_hash);
```

Then it works, can someone explain to me why that is? I am using C++17 if that makes a difference

EDIT:
Made a mistake, I have update the `sha1_hash` function to the correct one I call

## Solution:

I had two functions in the same namespace with the same name, as pointe out below, the clean solution in this case was to split into two namespace.
And as people have mentioned it was because the compiler could not choose which one to use.

Comment: Why it "works" or why you get the error in the first place?

Comment: What's unclear about the error? Arguments `const uint8_t* data, const size_t size, uint8_t* hash` does not match the expected arguments of `const std::vector<uint8_t>&, std::vector<uint8_t>&`. Your "dabbling in the dark" would invoke undefined behavior, once you called such a function.

Comment: It looks like the code under the hood (that you didn't provide) is trying to mix function pointers and data pointers.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius ahhh you actually answered the question thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sup>From the error message I suppose that `sha1_hash` is overloaded.</sup>

---

`void (*sha1_hash)(const std::vector<uint8_t>&, std::vector<uint8_t>&) = harpocrates::hashing::sha1_hash;` works because when taking the [address of an overloaded function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overloaded_address) overload resolution is performed, the overload whose signature matches the type of `sha1_hash` is selected, i.e. `void (*)(const std::vector<uint8_t>&, std::vector<uint8_t>&)`.

> In all these contexts, the function selected from the overload set is the function whose type matches the pointer to function, reference to function, or pointer to member function type that is expected by target: the object or reference being initialized, the left-hand side of the assignment, function or operator parameter, the return type of a function, the target type of a cast, or the type of the template parameter, respectively.

You can also use `static_cast` to specify explicitly.

```
auto sha1_hash = static_cast<void (*)(const std::vector<uint8_t>&, std::vector<uint8_t>&)>(harpocrates::hashing::sha1_hash);
```

As the error message said, `void* hash_func = (void*) &harpocrates::hashing::sha1_hash;` doesn't works because `void*` doesn't match either signature of overloaded `sha1_hash`, then overload resolution fails.

BTW: Trying to convert the function pointer to `void*` seems a bad idea, especially you don't need it at all for this case.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica ? OP tried to convert it to `void*`?

Comment: Where? I'm not seeing it.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica Yes, it's only visible in the error message. :(